# Starting pgAdmin III with stored passwords asks for password again

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, ubuntu

Starting pgAdmin III on kubuntu with stored password asks for password every time connecting to database giving error "Error connecting to the server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied". It ignores checkbox in store password field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found reason for this in [Postgresql mailing lists](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTimwNJ_G4LUBP0FMUh4r_DYnf8boaLVof394fffr@mail.gmail.com). Problem is when file `/home/user/.pgpass` has permisions more than u=rw 0600 pgAdmin ignores the file. Changing permisions for file resolves problem.

Comment: Thanks for following up with the solution when you found it.